# Figuring which design pattern to use?

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design

In most radio devices, we can configure the wave which we want to explore and listen to stations using the demodulation mode compatible with this type.

There are at least two types AM and FM. We can model the radio device in this case as the following:

```
class RadioDevice {
    void demodulate (String m) {
        if(m.equals("FM")
            /* FM modelation */
        else if(m.equals("AM")
            /* AM modelation */
    }
}
```

How can I apply the strategy pattern in this case?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please see this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use polymorphism ?

Make an interface:

```
interface Radio {
   void modulate();
}
```

And than implement 2 classes:

```
FMRadio implements Radio{

    public void demodule(){
      //FM modulation
    }
}

AMRadio implements Radio{

    public void demodule(){
      //AM modulation
    }
}
```

And than, in your main, you could go:

```
Radio myRadio = new FMRadio();
myRadio.demodule();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can have an interface that covers the contract for both AM and FM demodulation, you could use the Strategy pattern:

```java
Demodulator d; // interface Demodulator { byte[] demodulate(); }
switch(m) {
    case "AM":
        d = new AMDemodulator();
        break;
    case "FM"
        d = new FMDemodulator();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type '"+ m + "'"); // you could use an Enum instead of a String
}
d.demodulate(waves);
```

This allows you to switch the `Demodulator` part on the fly while keeping the rest of the program logic in common (no duplication).

Check this repo (not mine) for design patterns and examples: https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

To make it a proper Strategy pattern, I would add using a `Context` class to the previous answer of @Ladislav_M, that will wrap & encapsulate executing a particular strategy and give more flexibility to the code:

```
class Context {
    private Radio radio;

    public Context(Radio radio) {
        this.radio = radio;
    }

    public Object runStrategy() {
        radio.demodulate();
        // do any other stuff you want
        return ...
    }
}
```

The execution in `main` would become more convenient:

```
Context context = new Context(new FmRadio());
Object result = context.runStrategy();
```

Or you can inline the above:

```
Object result = (new Context(new FmRadio())).runStrategy();
```

Of course, you can choose the implementation of `Radio` in a `switch` block and just pass it as a variable to the `Context`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not a good use case for Strategy design pattern**, its simple inheritance case. Strategy is used *where the state of the object does not change but different algorithms apply at different times*. e.g. Paypackage computation for different roles of employees (e.g. Temporary, Permanent etc.). Important point here is Temporary employee can become Permanent one day.

**In the above case AM will never become FM in its life time**. hence Strategy is not right pattern for it. These are (probably) different classes with common behavior (if present) can be shifted to base class. If they show a common contract with clients then even interface will do the task.